# regarding mail sent from my custom registration form in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have created a custom registration form in Drupal 8, and now i want to sent a mail from the submission of the form. So I have did it like this

```html
This is my .module file
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function Registration_form_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $options = array(
    'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
  );
  switch ($key) {
    case 'contact_form':
      $message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
      break;
  }
}
```

```php
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
$mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
        $module = 'Registration_form';
        $key = 'contact_form'; // Replace with Your key
        $to = $form_state->getValue('Email');
        $params = array(
            'body' => 'test',
            'subject' => 'Website Information Request',
            );
        $langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();
        $send = true;
        $message['subject'] = t('nouveau contact ');
        $message['body'][] = t('test');


        $result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);
        if ($result['result'] != true) {
        $message = t('There was a problem sending your email notification to @email.', array('@email' => $to));
        drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
        \Drupal::logger('mail-log')->error($message);
        return;
        }
        else{
        $message = t('An email notification has been sent to @email ', array('@email' => $to));
        drupal_set_message($message);
        \Drupal::logger('mail-log')->notice($message);
        }
}
```

So my question is i'm using localhost in xampp and i want to sent a mail after submission of the form, but i'm getting this error
Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
There was a problem sending your email notification to ABC@gmail.com
So how I can resolve my problem, i have gone through whole sites but not able to find answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be with the email configuration. See if this article helps you:
https://stevepolito.design/blog/drupal-configure-smtp-module-work-gmail-updated/

Comment: Hi Carlos Andre Fonsec, 
It's working now.. Thanks..